# Navbar showing a little gap on two sides

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I currently use bootstrap 5 navbar, as you can see in the pic that when I press F12 it isn't fully using the spaces in the left, I want my elements to be in the left. I tried body{ margin:0px and padding:0px but still no result...

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/x15ajgkm/#&togetherjs=m57O5uOF5H

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY3i6.png)

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might get some flak from the community if you don't take the time to [read up on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

use `margin: 0px` for `h2`.

```
h2{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

working example:

```css
*{
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.navbar{
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
width: 100%;

background-size: cover;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;

}

.container-fluid{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container-sm{
  width: 100%;
  
}

.selectreg{
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.selectcity{
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.selectschool{
  outline: none;
  width: 75%;
}
.selecttype{
  
}
.selecttuition{
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h2{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ms-auto">
    <div class="container-sm ms-auto">
    <div class="region">
          <h2><img src="nav img/region.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">  Region</h2>
      
        <div class="selectreg">
          
            <select id="selectreg">
              <option value="1">N/A</option>
              <option value="2">Region I (Ilocos Region)</option>
              <option value="3">Region II (Cagayan Valley)</option>
              <option value="4">Region III (Central Luzon)</option>
              <option value="5">Region IV‑A (CALABARZON)</option>
              <option value="6">MIMAROPA Region</option>
              <option value="7">Cordillera Administrative Region (CAR)</option>
              <option value="8">National Capital Region (NCR)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        </div>
  </div> 

    
    <div class="container-sm">
      <div class="city">
      <h2><img src="nav img/city.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">  Cities</h2>
      <div class="selectcity">
         <select id="selectcity" class="selectcity">
          <option value="3">N/A</option>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value=""></option>
         </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container-sm">
      <div class="tuition">
      <h2><img src="nav img/university.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">  Tuition Range</h2>
      <div class="selecttuition">
         <select id="selecttuition" class="selecttuition">
          <option value="3">N/A</option>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value=""></option>
         </select>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-sm">
      <div class="school">
      <h2><img src="nav img/university.png"alt="" width="50" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">  Schools</h2>
      <div class="selectschool">
         <select id="selectschool" class="selectschool">
          <option value="">Public</option>
          <option value="">Private</option>
         </select>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-sm">
      <div class="search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit"><img src="nav img/search.png" width="30" class="d-inline-block align-text-top"></button>
   </div>
 </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [this the result](https://codepen.io/fcherini/pen/BaZJQLE) you want?

Changes I made on the html, only the first two lines:

```
<div class="container-fluid  ms-auto d-flex">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ms-auto flex-column">
```

Changes I made on the css, only remove width from navbar:

```
.navbar{
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: It's okay now, I tried ml-auto and now it's on the left.. Thank you! the width is the culprit....